# Confirm dialog jquery ui con metodo ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery-ui

quiero usar un dialog confirm de jquery ui que se ajecute al presionar un boton "guardar", que si se presiona "si" entonces que se ejecute un metodo $.ajax que guarda la informacion en la bd.
Esto es lo que tengo:

```
$('#btnGuardaInforme').on('click',function(e){
        var comentarios = $('#comentarios').val();
        var plan = $('#plan').val();
        var periodo = $('#txtperiodo').val();
        var idIndicador = $('input#textIdindicador').val();
        var resultado = $('#txtresultado').val();
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#dialog-confirm').dialog("open");


    });

    $( function () { //DIALOG CONFIRM
        $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
                resizable: false,
                autoOpen: false,
                height: "auto",
                width: 400,
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                 "Guardar": function() {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: 'post',
                            url: baseUrl + 'Informe/GuardaInforme',
                            data: {idIndicador: idIndicador, periodo: periodo, comentarios: comentarios, plan: plan,resultado: resultado},
                            success: function(){
                                console.log('Guardado ok');
                            },
                            error: function(){
                                console.log('error ajax al guardar informe');
                            }
                        });


                    console.log('ok confirm');
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                  },
                   Cancelar: function() {
                     $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                   }
                 }
        });
    });
```

La funcion del dialog la tengo fuera del evento click del boton y no se como pasarle las variables que enviara por ajax.

Comment: Daniel , por qué no capturas los valores `(comentarios,plan,periodo)` dentro del `click` del dialogo  y no en el click del `Boton`?

Comment: era tan facil como eso, gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te recomiendo hacer las variables globales, de esta forma no tendrás que pasarlas de una función a otra.

Ejemplo:

```js
var global = "variable global";

function display(local) {
 alert(global+"\n"+local);
}

display(global);
```

Puedes modificar tu código de la siguiente manera:

```js
var comentarios = "";
var plan = "";
var periodo = "";
var idIndicador = "";
var resultado = "";

$('#btnGuardaInforme').on('click',function(e){
        comentarios = $('#comentarios').val();
        plan = $('#plan').val();
        periodo = $('#txtperiodo').val();
        idIndicador = $('input#textIdindicador').val();
        resultado = $('#txtresultado').val();
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#dialog-confirm').dialog("open");


    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```